# Помогите создать класс для JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

Мне приходит от сервера вот такой ответ:

```
 {
  "request.id" : null,
  "list" : {
   "email1@email.com" : {
     "Type" : "1"
  },
  "email2@email.com" : {
     "Type" : "1"
  },
  "email3@email.com" : {
     "Type" : "1"
  }
 }
```

Как и в какой класс мне его преобразовать при помощи библиотеки JSON.Net на C#? Учитывая, что Email в List могут быть всегда разные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существуют несколько инструментов для генерации C# классов из *JSON* строки:

1. http://json2csharp.com
2. Если у вас установлено [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com) в Visual Studio, то выполните *Edit > Paste special > paste JSON as class.*
3. Можно воспользоваться бесплатной программой [jsonclassgenerator.exe](http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/downloads/get/631627)

Любой из этих инструментов на выходе дает классы, используемые для сериализации/десериализации JSON строки.
Сам лично в большинстве случаем пользуюсь инструментом под номером 3.

На выходе для вашего примера он дает следующие классы

```
namespace Example
{

    internal class SampleResponse1
    {

        [JsonProperty("request.id")]
        public object RequestId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("list")]
        public List List { get; set; }
    }

}

namespace Example.SampleResponse1JsonTypes
{

    internal class List
    {

        [JsonProperty("email1@email.com")]
        public Email1EmailCom Email1EmailCom { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("email2@email.com")]
        public Email2EmailCom Email2EmailCom { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("email3@email.com")]
        public Email3EmailCom Email3EmailCom { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Email1EmailCom
    {

        [JsonProperty("Type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Email2EmailCom
    {

        [JsonProperty("Type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
    internal class Email3EmailCom
    {
        [JsonProperty("Type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

}
```

> Учитывая, что Email в List могут быть всегда разные.

В таком случае, для генерации С# классов ваш JSON должен модифицироваться в такой вид

```
{
  "request.id" : null,
  "list" : [
   {
     "email" :
     {
        Name:  "email1@email.com",
        Type: "1"
     },
     "email" :
     {
        Name:  "email2@email.com",
        Type: "1"
     }
   }]
}
```

Иначе вы не сможете сгенерировать классы с переменным названием класса.  Изменяемая часть не должна быть ключом JSON-объекта. **Для генерации C# классов ключи JSON объектов должны быть фиксированными. Ключ содержит в себе название генерируемого класса.**
Либо нужно попробовать переписать этот пример через Dictionary. В итоге получился такой вариант.

```
namespace Example
{

    internal class SampleResponse1
    {

        [JsonProperty("request.id")]
        public object RequestId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("list")]
        public Dictionary<string, Email> List { get; set; }
    }

}
namespace Example.SampleResponse1JsonTypes
{  
    class Email
    {
       [JsonProperty("type")]
       public string Type{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Все верно, так пробовал. Но мне надо, учесть, что EMAIL в LIST могут быть разные всегда. Т.е. это просто список адресов, которые отдает мне API. Как быть в этом случае?

Comment: @Cepega, http://pastebin.com/h12vMLRc как вариант. Получится словарь где ключ(строка)=email и значение - класс с данными для него

Comment: Спасибо, с public Dictionary<string, Email> List { get; set; } помогло решение.

Answer (score 4):

Так как любой javascript объект можно представить в виде словаря, то класс может иметь следующий вид

```
class SampleResponse1
{

    [JsonProperty("request.id")]
    public object RequestId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("list")]
    public Dictionary<string,Email> List { get; set; }
}
```

Где Email - это

```
class Email{
    public string Type{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я вижу ещё следующие опции (ориентируясь на ещё более нетривиальные варианты, чем в вопросе):
Так как объекты и свойства могут разными можно

1. Сериализовать в ExpandoObject (по сути представляет словарь со свойствами), затем по нему итерируюсь посмотреть что за свойства.
   `var expandoObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(carPropertiesJson, new
   ExpandoObjectConverter());`
2. Сгенерировать классы с помощью T4.
   Инструкции и руководства можно найти на MSDN:
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff697256.aspx
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126478.aspx
   T4 является невероятно мощным инструментом, позволяющим также сгенерировать несколько файлов (причём любых расширений) и выполнять произвольный код.